# Cannot add or update a child row when registering an account

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a registration form on my website that will issue customers with a user_id which is the parent table and then a member_id in the member table. The member table references the parent table however wont seem to store the foreign key. Im not sure how to solve this problem and im very new to sql.

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails(`gadgets`.`member`, CONSTRAINT `member_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

```
Query: INSERT INTO member (first_name, last_name, address, city, post_code, phone, email, date) VALUES ('bob', 'all','33 wildown','london','n4','020','bob', NOW())

     CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `member` (
  `member_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `post_code` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `phone` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`member_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=20 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `user`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('member','admin') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'member',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=19 ;

-- Constraints for table `member`
--
ALTER TABLE `member`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `member_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Here is my php

if (empty($errors)) { // If everything's OK.

```
    // Register the user in the database...

    // Make the query:
    $q2 = "INSERT INTO user ( username, password) VALUES ('$un', SHA1('$p') )";
    $q = "INSERT INTO member (first_name, last_name, address, city, post_code, phone, email, date) VALUES ('$fn', '$ln','$a','$c','$pc','$pn','$e', NOW())";


    $r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q2);
    $r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);

    // Run the query.
    if ($r) { // If it ran OK.

        // Print a message:
        echo '<h1>Thank you!</h1>
    <p>You are now registered.</p><p><br /></p>';   

    } else { // If it did not run OK.

        // Public message:
        echo '<h1>System Error</h1>
        <p class="error">You could not be registered due to a system error. We apologize for any inconvenience.</p>'; 

        // Debugging message:
        echo '<p>' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '<br /><br />Query: ' . $q . '</p>';

    } // End of if ($r) IF.

    mysqli_close($dbc); // Close the database connection.

    // Include the footer and quit the script:
    include ('includes/footer.html'); 
    exit();

} else { // Report the errors.

    echo '<h1>Error!</h1>
    <p class="error">The following error(s) occurred:<br />';
    foreach ($errors as $msg) { // Print each error.
        echo " - $msg<br />\n";
```

Comment: can't you not combine the user and member table into one table ? Is there any application design constraint on that ?

Comment: Ive been told that I have to do it this way :/

Answer (score 1):

You need to retrieve the user_id from the first insert and include it in your second insert if you are going to use it as a foreign key. You are trying to create a record in the member table without specifying the user_id but your CREATE statement sets it as NOT NULL.

Comment: How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Would I Have to use a select statement then insert?

Comment: Check out the documentation here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html